# How to remove the header from a Google document once added

Tags: google-docs, headers

Once you add a header to a Google document, it offsets the top of the document even if empty, and receives click events. How can you then remove the header?

I am aware that you can reduce the header's effects by decreasing the page's top margin, and reducing the font size in the header—those are not the solutions I am looking for. I would like a way to actually REMOVE it.

Comment: To be clear: I'm also not looking for "Control+z/Edit->Undo" or the like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**edit**

There's an Add-on available that removes the header or footer in the active document only once added:

**[Documents by Top Contributors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/documents-by-top-contribu/legopboheadejbmpbakifohpkoipopjh?utm_source=permalink)**

[image]

Goto your Google Document and choose from the menu *Add-ons > Get add-ons...* and search for:

[image]

<sub>Affiliation: I wrote the add-on</sub>

---

The following line of code will reset the header (gray line disappears).

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("Header / Footer")
    .addItem("Reset header", "resetHeader")
    .addItem("Reset footer", "resetFooter")
    .addToUi()
}

function resetHeader() {
  try {
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader().removeFromParent();
  } catch(e) {
    throw "No header present !!";
  }
}

function resetFooter() {
  try {
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter().removeFromParent();
  } catch(e) {
    throw "No footer present !!";
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

*before*
[image]

*after*
[image]

### Note

I've noticed that after running the script (and thus removing the header or footer), adding them wasn't possible on the document I was working on.

Add the code under *Tools > Script editor...*, press the bug button to authenticate the script and then press the play button. This will "play" the code and reset the header.

*edit*
See Google Help Forum for an extensive walk-through: **[How to remove the header in Google Docs?](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/Jpmzhp6qU6Y/g24fuBPDo-MJ)**

Comment: Was a little awkward of a solution, but it worked like a charm.  I blame the awkwardness on Google.

Comment: Doesn't work: TypeError: Cannot call method "removeFromParent" of null. (line 2, file "Code").

Comment: @fossilet: It needs to have a header in the first place. Did you have a header?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, I had a footer instead. Maybe I should change the function names?

Comment: This worked for me, and really saved the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy all your text and then get a new doc. Paste it onto there and you're done

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @jonsca It does actually, because there's no way to remove it (other than some script, which I won't count). Scripts are utterly stupid way to achieve this for the same reason as why you won't write a script to remove the bold from a line of text. No idea what they were thinking implementing the headers but not implementing removing them (WTF stuff right there).