# Remove line below table in header

Tags: google-docs

I have a table in my header, after the table I would like for the content of my page to just start, but there there is a line after the table that I cannot remove which is making my spacing not work the way I want it to.

To demonstrate what I mean check out this [quick example document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10bEm4ZzE7NoroevCzM0VwWgcMG7Wy3frf4AfUHrzQLE/edit?usp=sharing) I made that shows the problem. I have some text on the line I would like to remove, I would have thought I could just delete that text and press backspace but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible to do, without [removing the header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73318/29140) altogether.

There are two ways to reduce the spacing:

1. lower the font size from 11 to 6 points
2. lower the line spacing from 1.15 to 1

The changes are not big, but perhaps enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way of removing it completely. You could delete the text and make it 1pt in size, which would reduce the gap at least.